# Unable to authorize on FreeRADIUS

Tags: freeradius

I have installed `FreeRADIUS2` from tarball and added a new user in `raddb/users` as

```
_aboli Cleartext-Password := "safarnama"_
```

But when I try to authorize, I get following error:

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 192.168.9.128 port 60663, id=191, length=51  
    User-Name = 'aboli'  
    User-Password = 'safarnama'  
    NAS-Port = 0  
(0) WARNING: Empty authorize section.  Using default return values.
(0) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user. 
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject  
(0) WARNING: Unknown value specified for Post-Auth-Type.  Cannot perform requested action.  
(0) Finished request 0.  
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

The message `WARNING: Empty authorize section.  Using default return values.` means that you've got nothing in the authorize{} section of your virtual server config (most likely `/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default` or possibly `/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf` if you've been editing that).

Verify that you've installed FreeRADIUS correctly with the full configuration. This is the most basic configuration, so after a new install then all you should need to do is edit the `users` file as you have done above, then try running `radtest` from the local machine to make sure it works. Once you've done that and it works then add an entry into `clients.conf` and move to testing over the network from another machine.

These days you should be using FreeRADIUS version 3. Version 2 is end-of-life.